# Create a function that takes a word, and returns a random letter from it

Tags: python

I am very new to programming and mainly guessing, please help!

I am trying to answer an exercise question, 'Create a function that takes a word, and returns a random letter from it.'

I have chosen the word 'caramel', I have stated the length of the word and assigned the number of the length of the word to the letters.

#create a function that takes a function and returns a random letter from it.

```
my_word = 'caramel'
len(my_word)

random.randrange(1,7)


'caramel'[0]=='a'
'caramel'[1]=='a'
'caramel'[2]=='r'
'caramel'[3]=='a'
'caramel'[4]=='m'
'caramel'[5]=='e'
'caramel'[6]=='l'

random.randrange('my_word'[1,7])
```

#how do get the code to return a random letter?

Comment: A lot of syntax issues here makes it hard to know where to start.  The lines in the form of `'caramel'[0]=='a'` aren't really doing anything, and aren't assigning anything.  The first line evaluates to Flse (because ``'caramel'[0]` == `'c'`) while the others evaluate to True.  Strings are immutable in Python and you can't change individual characters with the `=` operator.  Then in your use of randrange, the function expects to integers to be passed in as parameters, but instead you are passing it the string `'y_word'`

Comment: Instead of guessing, I recommend following a beginner's guide or a tutorial. Harvard offers a free beginner's Python course at https://cs50.harvard.edu/python/2022.  There are free e-books such as [Automate the Boring Stuff](https://automatetheboringstuff.com/)  (Note - some of the later lessons are slightly out of date on how to setup the necessary packages).  And there is the python.org [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use choice from module random:

```
import random

def random_letter(string: str):
    return random.choice(string)
```

**EDIT:**
There is no need to define the length of the word. You can just call this function using statement

```
random_character = random_letter("whatever string you wish")
```

and it will set your variable *random_character* to some random character.

Answer (score 2):

This is unnecessary. You could simply do:

```py
import random
def get_random_char():
    return random.choice("caramel")
```

or more generally:

```py
import random
def get_random_char(word):
    return random.choice(word)
```

Comment: `word` in `random.choice("word")` should not be in quotes

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I've fixed it now.